# What are the differences between Detached and Modified Entity Framework State?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

what are the differences between detached and modified? What are the disadvantages of using detached

Comment: _"I learned that the record will be updated with Detached as well."_ where have you learned that?

Comment: I saw that a few fields were updated instead of all fields. Data is not fully updated when Detached is used. I fixed the question.

Comment: Can you please share the code you used for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

According to msdn :

**Detached:** the entity is not being tracked by the context.

**Modified:** the entity is being tracked by the context and exists in the database, and some or all of its property values have been modified.

Modified entities are updated in the database and then become Unchanged when SaveChanges returns. With Detached nothing happened actually; just context is not tracking this entity and will not update any part of it.

You can find deatils of entity states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state).

If you want to attach an detached entity to context you have to explicitly point it and set the state of this entity modified after attached it.

```
public override void Update(T entity)
{
  var entry = _context.Entry<T>(entity);

  if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
  {
        _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
  }
}
```

You can find more information about detached entities and how to attched them [here](https://blog.maskalik.com/entity-framework/2013/12/23/entity-framework-updating-database-from-detached-objects/).

Comment: Before updating, I am making a get request with the id parameter. I successfully updated the data when I wrote the `AsNoTracking()` command on the base repository that made the get request.

Comment: @burakergun if you are making crud operations on your entity better you don't use AsNoTracking(). Let context track it and take care of changes. AsNoTracking is efficient with querying scenarious that you show data with out modifiying. But if you have some specific case just share codes you have.